# Jsx indentation conflict vscode and eslint

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint-config-airbnb

Eslint(airbnb config) wants to have my params on new lines when I have multiple params. But when I do that, vscode formatting keeps giving 4 spaces indentation instead of 2 as expected.

Result:

```
const Example = ({
  param1,
  param2,
  param3,
}) => (
    <div>
      {param1} {param2} {param3}
    </div>
  );
```

expected:

```
const Example = ({
  param1,
  param2,
  param3,
}) => (
  <div>
    {param1} {param2} {param3}
  </div>
);
```

Is there a setting I can use in vscode to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid conflicting rules by using [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) or preferably [prettier-eslint](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint) integration. This integration will use eslint config for formatting the rules and there won't be any conflicts.

If you are using VS Code, there is a config option for [prettier-vscode](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettiereslintintegration-default-false---javascript-and-typescript-only)